# Determine platform under JNA for setsockopt

Tags: java, sockets, jna

I'm writing an implementation of `setsockopt` under JNA. Java itself [supports setsockopt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/socketOpt.html), but it doesn't support all the platform specific socket options. For instance, it doesn't support `[TCP_KEEPIDLE][2]` under Linux. Clearly, many of these options are not very portable, and using JNA is a route to poor portability; I am aware of this. Please don't bother to tell me the idea is deeply horrible.

What I'd like to do, however, is make my code a little more reuseable than something that just works under Linux. I'd like it to work (as far as is possible) on several target platforms. If the socket option is not available, it can throw an exception.

My challenge is this. The JNA works fine, but the values of the socket options are different across platforms. For instance, `SO_RCVBUF` is `0x1002` under OS-X and `8` under Linux (I realise `SO_RCVBUF` is controllable by the normal Java `setSockOpt` - it's an example that's easy to test with `lsof`). `SO_DONTROUTE` is `5` under Linux, and `0x0010` under OS-X (and that isn't controllable via Java `setSockOpt`).

So what I'd like it to do is to take an `enum` value representing the socket option (`SO_SNDBUF`, `SO_RCVBUF` or whatever), and look that up in a platform dependent map, so I get `0x1002` / `0x010` under OS-X and `8` / `5` under Linux.

That's easy enough, but how do I tell what the platform is under JNA so I know which map to use? JNA must somehow have a sense of its own platform, or it would not (I presume) know how to call the native libraries.

```
package sockettest;

import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.net.Socket;

import com.sun.jna.LastErrorException;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;

public class JNASockOpt {

    private static Field fdField;
    static {
        Native.register("c");
        try {
            fdField = FileDescriptor.class.getDeclaredField("fd");
            fdField.setAccessible(true);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            fdField = null;
        }
    }

    public static int getInputFd(Socket s) {
        try {
            FileInputStream in = (FileInputStream)s.getInputStream();
            FileDescriptor fd = in.getFD();
            return fdField.getInt(fd);
        } catch (Exception e) { }
        return -1;
    }

    public static int getOutputFd(Socket s) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream in = (FileOutputStream)s.getOutputStream();
            FileDescriptor fd = in.getFD();
            return fdField.getInt(fd);
        } catch (Exception e) { }
        return -1;
    }

    public static int getFd(Socket s) {
        int fd = getInputFd(s);
        if (fd != -1)
            return fd;
        return getOutputFd(s);
    }

    // The list of SOL_ and SO_ options is platform dependent
    public static final int SOL_SOCKET = 0xffff; // that's under OS-X, but it's 1 under Linux
    public static final int SO_RCVBUF = 0x1002; // that's under OS-X, but it's 8 under Linux
    public static final int SO_DONTROUTE = 0x0010; // that's under OS-X, but it's 5 under Linux

    private static native int setsockopt(int fd, int level, int option_name, Pointer option_value, int option_len) throws LastErrorException;

    public static void setSockOpt (Socket socket, int level, int option_name, int option_value) throws IOException {
        if (socket == null)
            throw new IOException("Null socket");
        int fd = getFd(socket);
        if (fd == -1)
            throw new IOException("Bad socket FD");
        IntByReference val = new IntByReference(option_value);
        try {
            setsockopt(fd, level, option_name, val.getPointer(), 4);
        } catch (LastErrorException ex) {
            throw new IOException("setsockopt: " + strerror(ex.getErrorCode()));
        }
    }

    public static native String strerror(int errnum);

    private JNASockOpt() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jnaplatform` does this by string parsing `System.getProperty("os.name");`, which seems pretty horrible to me, but if `jnaplatform` does it, I guess that should be good enough for me.

Results (i.e. how I used the above idea to solve the issue in the question) at https://github.com/abligh/jnasockopt - specifically https://github.com/abligh/jnasockopt/blob/master/src/org/jnasockopt/JNASockOptionDetails.java

Comment: This answer might lead to people thinking [https://github.com/abligh/jnasockopt](https://github.com/abligh/jnasockopt) is the JNA library.

Comment: I find it difficult to see how this answer possibly be parsed to mean that. The question I asked was "That's easy enough, but how do I tell what the platform is under JNA so I know which map to use?", and I answered in respect in jnaplatform, then showed what *I'd* done in order to use it. Irrespective, I will make it staggeringly obvious by edit that that isn't the case.

Comment: Agreed, when carefully reading the question as well as the answers and noticing that the accepted answer is the same person as the one who asked the question, then it becomes clear that your library isn't the JNA library. However, a lot of people -including me- don't take the time to read everything carefully. So, for people like me, you could mention that you're referring to your own library. Also, on GitHub, it's sometimes hard to find the 'right' library with all those forks. Anyway, thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 1):

The class [`com.sun.jna.Platform`](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.1.0/com/sun/jna/Platform.html) provided by JNA is used by JNA itself and has functions for querying the OS family and CPU architecture.

There are static methods for `isMac()` and `isLinux()`.